# How to extract one line followed by range of lines

Tags: awk

I'm trying to extract a single line containing `domain:` followed by range of lines from `nameservers"` to `]`.  I know how to do these things separately using `grep` and `awk` respectively but not sure how to do it at once.

Input data:

```
domain: stackexchange.com date: Mon Jul 3 00:43:49 2017 output_dir:        /tmp/stackexchange.com.12653
INFO:root:crawl: exiting dom: 'stackexchange.com' took: 10s
INFO:root:2017-07-03 00:44:06:370 slave.py: exiting args.url: 'stackexchange.com' took: 3s
+ comparing web systems

  "mail_server_ip": [],              |   "mail_server_ip": []
  "nameservers": [
    "ns-925.awsdns-51.net.",
    "ns-1029.awsdns-00.org.",
    "ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.",
    "ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com.",
  ],
  "nameservers_domains": [           |   "nameservers_domains": [], 
    "m
```

Desired output:

```
  domain: stackexchange.com date: Mon Jul 3 00:43:49 2017 output_dir:        
  "nameservers": [
    "ns-925.awsdns-51.net.",
    "ns-1029.awsdns-00.org.",
    "ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.",
    "ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com.",
  ],
```

Commands to extract data separately:

```
  grep "domain:" test_sample.txt      
  awk '/nameservers"/,/]/' test_sample.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**awk** approach

```
awk '/^domain:/{print}/"nameservers":/,/]/' test_sample.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

***grep*** approach with `P` (*PCRE*) option:

```
grep -Poz 'domain: .+ output_dir:|\s*"nameservers": \[[^][]+\],\n' test_sample.txt
```

The output:

```
domain: stackexchange.com date: Mon Jul 3 00:43:49 2017 output_dir:
  "nameservers": [
    "ns-925.awsdns-51.net.",
    "ns-1029.awsdns-00.org.",
    "ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.",
    "ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com.",
  ],
```

---

The main pattern is based on regex alternation group `<domain_line>|<nameservers_lines>`